# nhibernate - hbm xml - complicated property ref attribute

Tags: nhibernate-mapping, hbmxml

I using nhibernate with hbm files (not fluent).
In the mapping hbm file, 
I need to use the attribute property-ref but not in the simple way. I need to access to an inner proprty of an object.

I need to use it like this:
property-ref="object.property"
but it doesn't work...

Any suggestions?

Comment: if possible, show more. The C# code and mapping you've got so far. That could help to find out...